# Windows Task Scheduler API 2.0 make task miss (only)next scheduled time

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com

While using the Windows Task Scheduler API 2.0, how does one set or unset the option: ***"run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed"***. I have already create multiple types of tasks using the API in c++, but I can't seem to find where you set this option...
I guess I found it: [StartWhenAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .
I also would like to be able to run the task on demand within the api code.
I think I allow on demand running using: [put_AllowDemandStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but how do I run it from withing the code?
I guess this is it : [IRegisteredTask::Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But... How do you make a task miss its next scheduled time?

Comment: Easy, pull the power cord.

Comment: Yes, that should do it :))